# Listeners wouldn't work when a serialized panel is deserialized and retrieved (Java)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, listener

I'm designing a JPanel in which there are some buttons which have their own action listeners and would do certain things when clicked (for example, one of them would remove the panel). In case the user closes the program, panels shouldn't be deleted and should be retrieved. for this purpose I serialize panels and deserialize them when needed. but the problem is listeners such as action listeners and mouse listeners wouldn't work when the panel is retrieved. is there any way to solve this problem? or is there any alternative to do the same thing without problem?
My panel code in case it's needed:

```
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.commons.SerialVersionUIDAdder;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.Format;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Random;

public class Download extends JPanel implements Serializable {
    private String fileName;
    private boolean removed = false;
    private double downloadSpeed;
    private double downloadedSize;
    private double sizeOfFile;
    LocalTime downloadTime;
    LocalDate downloadDate;
    private boolean checked = false;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095L;
    JLabel test = new JLabel("test");


    public Download (MainPage c,URL url,LocalTime time,LocalDate date) {

        setLayout(null);
        downloadDate = date;
        downloadTime = time;
        fileName = url.getFile();
        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        checkbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    setChecked(true);
                else
                    setChecked(false);
            }
        });
        checkbox.setBackground(new Color(186,212,215));
        checkbox.setBounds(95,42,17,15);
        add(checkbox);
        MouseAdapter a = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseEntered(e);
                setBackground(new Color(224,235,252));
                checkbox.setBackground(new Color(224,235,252));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseExited(e);
                setBackground(new Color(186,212,255));
                checkbox.setBackground(new Color(186,212,255));
            }
        };
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", new Color (235,255,255));
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", new Color (10,109,63));
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.RED);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.GREEN);
        setBackground(new Color(186,212,255));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        JPanel file = new JPanel();
      /*  test fileImg = new test("file.png");
        fileImg.setBounds(10,10,40,50);
        add(fileImg); */
        JLabel fileNameLabel = new JLabel(fileName);
        fileNameLabel.setBounds(100,5,400,15);
        fileNameLabel.setForeground(new Color(109,111,114));
        add(fileNameLabel);
        JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        Random r = new Random();
        jpb.setValue(r.nextInt(100));
        jpb.setBounds(100,25,400,10);
        JLabel progressBarValue = new JLabel("%" + jpb.getValue() + "");
        progressBarValue.setBounds(510,18,25,20);
        add(progressBarValue);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,2,0,new Color(18,42,79)));
        addMouseListener(a);
        add(jpb);
        JButton trash = new JButton(new ImageIcon("trash.png"));
        trash.setBounds(130,40,25,25);
    /*    trash.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        trash.setFocusPainted (false);
        trash.setBorderPainted(false); */
        trash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("text");
            }
        });
        add(trash);

        test.setBounds(180,40,25,25);
        test.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e);
                System.out.println("text");
            }
        });
        add(test);
        double lower = 0;
        double upper = 999.99;
        sizeOfFile = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;
        downloadSpeed = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;
        downloadedSize = jpb.getValue() * sizeOfFile / 100;
        JLabel downloadSpeedLabel = new JLabel (String.format ("%.1fKbs",downloadSpeed));
        JLabel downloadedSizeLabel = new JLabel (String.format ("%.1fMG / %.2fMG",downloadedSize,sizeOfFile));
        downloadedSizeLabel.setForeground(new Color(109,111,114));
        downloadSpeedLabel.setForeground(new Color(109,111,114));
        downloadSpeedLabel.setBounds(250,35,100,30);
        downloadedSizeLabel.setBounds(420,35,150,30);
        add(downloadSpeedLabel); add(downloadedSizeLabel);






    }

    public boolean isRemoved() {
        return removed;
    }

    public void setRemoved(boolean removed) {
        this.removed = removed;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public double getDownloadSpeed() {
        return downloadSpeed;
    }

    public void setDownloadSpeed(double downloadSpeed) {
        this.downloadSpeed = downloadSpeed;
    }

    public double getDownloadedSize() {
        return downloadedSize;
    }

    public void setDownloadedSize(double downloadedSize) {
        this.downloadedSize = downloadedSize;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public double getSizeOfFile() {
        return sizeOfFile;
    }

    public void setSizeOfFile(double size) {
        this.sizeOfFile = size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to serialize a program's view and its listeners? This question has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) written all over it. The better solution is to change your approach entirely and only serialize your program's model, and then use the state of the model to recreate the view (the GUI) when needed.

Comment: I'm not trying to serialize a program's view. I'm designing a download manager which consists of panels representing each item which is being downloaded. when the program is closed, I need to retrieve the items that user have chosen to download before. that's why I serialize each download panel.

Comment: Exactly -- you're serializing JPanels, meaning your serializing your view, which again is madness. Instead create a model class that represents the data held by a typical JPanel and serialize that. And read up on MVC (model-view-controller) to better understand what I'm suggesting.

Comment: I got your point, thank you sir.